# Ошибка запроса retrofit2 yandexsdk. Ошибка Attempt to invoke virtual method?

Tags: android, запрос, retrofit, yandexsdk

**Здесь формируется на отправку запрос(в документации яндекс написано, что параметры path и from должны иметь url формат, я его написал вручную:**

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    RestClient client = null;
                    try {

                        client = RestClientUtil.getInstance(credentials);
                        client.move("%2F1.jpg", "%2F211.jpg", false);
                    } catch (HttpCodeException ex) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "renameMoveItem", ex);
                        sendException(ex.getResponse().getDescription());
                    } catch (IOException | ServerException ex) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "renameMoveItem", ex);
                        sendException(ex);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    RenameMoveItemFragment targetFragment = (RenameMoveItemFragment) getTargetFragment();
                    if (targetFragment != null) {
                        targetFragment.onComplete();
                    }
                }
            }.execute();
        }
```

**вот сам интерфейс c sdk:**

```
@POST("/v1/disk/resources/move")
    Link move(@Query("from") String from, @Query("path") String path,
              @Query("overwrite") Boolean overwrite)
            throws IOException, ServerIOException;
```

**ВОТ ЛОГИ:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                    Process: com.example.gibkin.multycloud, PID: 10297
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.gibkin.multycloud.yandex.example.IODialogRetainedFragment.sendException(IODialogRetainedFragment.java:32)
                                                                                   at com.example.gibkin.multycloud.yandex.example.IODialogRetainedFragment.sendException(IODialogRetainedFragment.java:28)
                                                                                   at com.example.gibkin.multycloud.yandex.example.RenameMoveItemFragment$RenameMoveItemRetainedFragment$1.doInBackground(RenameMoveItemFragment.java:144)
                                                                                   at com.example.gibkin.multycloud.yandex.example.RenameMoveItemFragment$RenameMoveItemRetainedFragment$1.doInBackground(RenameMoveItemFragment.java:130)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Вы где-то `post` вызываете, а то что слева от него - `null`

Comment: `protected void sendException(final String message) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                IODialogFragment targetFragment = (IODialogFragment) getTargetFragment();
                if (targetFragment != null) {
                    targetFragment.sendException(message);
                }
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: это код с sdk яндекс диска

Comment: У вас `handler` `null`

Comment: например, при сохранении файла на телефон выскакивает ошибка 416,а как с ней бороться?

Comment: Вы определитесь-у вас NPE или 416?

Comment: npe это ошибка когда я патаюсь переименовать файл

Comment: вот,что ответил парень из яндекса:
_А при чём тут Яндекс, собственно? Ошибка в вашем коде, конкретно в методе sendException, в классе IODialogRetainedFragment, на 32 строке. Код вы не приложили, но там есть Handler и вы у него дёргаете метод post, хотя он null. 

Магия, правда? Учитесь читать стек-трейсы.

P.S. У вас утекает(memory leak) фрагмент вместе с активити из-за этой асинктаски._

Comment: Всё верно ответили - пролема не в яндексе, если у вас NPE

Comment: Так это же их код)))

Comment: И что? Это мог написать кто-то плохо разбирающийся. Код от %CompanyName% не обязательно является эталонным и вообще рабочим

Comment: он ужасен, так как в эру retrofit 2 асинк таском пользоваться для осуществления запросов просто убого

Comment: Раз вы сами это понимаете, то зачем его используете и удивляетесь его неработоспособности? И раз это понимаете то почему не знаете что такое NPE и что с ним делать?

Comment: так я же вам писал) я остановился на построении билдера для яндекса, и все ) ошибку не мог исправить.

Comment: Вы меня окончательно запутали. Я более не понимаю что у вас за ошибка и какова задача.

Comment: я получил токен с помощью стандартного метода java. как мне теперь создать builder  retrofit2?

Comment: Я не вижу никакой связи между наличием токена и созданием билдера.